# How to add anchor tag in Pandoc Markdown to HTML conversion to avoid URI encoding?

Tags: html, markdown, anchor, pandoc

I'm writing a blog in Markdown that i convert to HTML using Pandoc.
I want to add an Amazon affiliate links which is given as a HTML tag

```
<a href="https://www.amazon.com/Programming-Haskell-Graham-Hutton...s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1...
"></a>
```

I need Pandoc to place it "raw" into the converted HTML file. This works with simple anchor tag like:

```
<a name="linkTarget"></a>
```

They appear "as is" in the HTML file.
However, because the href attribute in the amazon anchor tag is URI-encoded, Pandoc seems to get confused. It HTML-encodes the anchor tag to:

```
&lt;a href=&quot;https://www.amazon.com/...
```

How do i avoid this?

Comment: what exact command are you using? cannot reproduce. Also, why are you using `<a>` instead of markdown link notation? Finally, try with the newest pandoc version.

Comment: Thanks. The Ubuntu pandoc version was an old 1.16. I upgraded to the newest 1.19 version and the erroneous behavior is gone. (I wanted to use the raw amazon anchor links with images, because i didn't know there was a method to use images as link with normal markdown as:https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2133/whats-the-recommended-syntax-for-an-image-with-a-link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading to the latest pandoc version solved my problem.